# Bug in Player Movement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm currently facing a lot of challenges with player movement as I'm quite new to Unity. I'm trying to implement a movement similar to Wander from "Shadow of the Colossus," where the player can smoothly move in eight directions. However, in my script, the player seems to start sliding instead of walking in those directions as I intended. I'm reaching out for some guidance on how to achieve this type of movement successfully. Your assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjDmn.png)

I've set up the InputActions in the movement Vector3 for the player, using the CharacterController. However, it seems that now the character is sliding instead of moving smoothly in the "8 directions" as intended.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

[RequireComponent(typeof(CharacterController))]
public class PlayerLocomotionManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float Velocity;
    [Space]
    public float InputX;
    public float InputZ;
    public Vector3 desiredMoveDirection;
    public bool blockRotationPlayer;
    public float desiredRotationSpeed = 0.1f;
    public Animator animator;
    public float Speed;
    public float allowPlayerRotation = 0.1f;
    public Camera cam;
    public CharacterController controller;
    public bool isGrounded;
    public bool isJump;
    public PlayerControls playerControls;
    [Header("Animation Smoothing")]
    [Range(0, 1f)]
    public float HorizontalAnimSmoothTime = 0.2f;
    [Range(0, 1f)]
    public float VerticalAnimTime = 0.2f;
    [Range(0, 1f)]
    public float StartAnimTime = 0.3f;
    [Range(0, 1f)]
    public float StopAnimTime = 0.15f;
    public float verticalVel;
    private Vector3 moveVector;
    private Vector2 movementInput = Vector2.zero;
    private float jumpForce = 5f;
    private float groundCheckDistance = 0.5f;
    private float gravityValue = -9.81f;
    //controls
    private InputAction Move;
    private InputAction Jump;
    private void Start()
    {
        animator = this.GetComponent<Animator>();
        cam = Camera.main;
        controller = this.GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }



    private void Awake()
    {
        playerControls = new PlayerControls();

        Jump = playerControls.PlayerMovement.Jump;
        Move = playerControls.PlayerMovement.Movement;

        Jump.performed += onJumpInput;
        Move.performed += onMovementInput;
    }

    public void OnEnable()
    {
        playerControls.Enable();
        Move = playerControls.PlayerMovement.Movement;
        Jump = playerControls.PlayerMovement.Jump;
        Jump.Enable();
        Move.Enable();
    }
    public void OnDisable()
    {
        playerControls.Disable();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        HandleMovement();
        HandleJump();

        isGrounded = controller.isGrounded;
        if (isGrounded)
        {
            verticalVel -= 0;
        }
        else
        {
            verticalVel -= 1;
        }
        moveVector = new Vector3(0, verticalVel * .2f * Time.deltaTime, 0).normalized;
        controller.Move(moveVector);

    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        CheckGround();
    }

    void onMovementInput(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        movementInput = Move.ReadValue<Vector2>();
        Debug.Log("Movement Input: " + movementInput);
    }

    void onJumpInput(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        if (context.phase == InputActionPhase.Performed)
        {
            isJump = true; // Set the Jump bool to true when the jump input is performed
            HandleJump();
        }
        else if (context.phase == InputActionPhase.Canceled)
        {
            isJump = false;
        }

        Debug.Log("Jump Input: Performed");
    }

    private void HandleMovement()
    {
       

        var camera = Camera.main;
        var forward = cam.transform.forward;
        var right = cam.transform.right;

        forward.y = 0f;
        right.y = 0f;

        forward.Normalize();
        right.Normalize();

        desiredMoveDirection = forward * movementInput.y + right * movementInput.x ;

        if (blockRotationPlayer == false)
        {
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(desiredMoveDirection), desiredRotationSpeed);
            controller.Move(desiredMoveDirection * Time.deltaTime * Velocity);
        }
    }

    private void HandleJump()
    {
        if (isJump && isGrounded)
        {
            verticalVel = jumpForce;
            animator.SetTrigger("Jump");
        }

        verticalVel += gravityValue * Time.deltaTime;
        moveVector = new Vector3(0, verticalVel, 0).normalized;
        controller.Move(moveVector * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    public void LookAt(Vector3 pos)
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(pos), desiredRotationSpeed);
    }

    public void RotateToCamera(Transform t)
    {
        var camera = Camera.main;
        var forward = cam.transform.forward;
        var right = cam.transform.right;

        desiredMoveDirection = forward;

        t.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(desiredMoveDirection), desiredRotationSpeed);
    }

    private void UpdateMovementAnimations()
    {

        //anim.SetFloat ("InputZ", InputZ, VerticalAnimTime, Time.deltaTime * 2f);
        //anim.SetFloat ("InputX", InputX, HorizontalAnimSmoothTime, Time.deltaTime * 2f);

        //Calculate the Input Magnitude
        Speed = new Vector2(movementInput.x, movementInput.y).sqrMagnitude;

        //Physically move player

        if (Speed > allowPlayerRotation)
        {
            animator.SetFloat("Speed", Speed, StartAnimTime, Time.deltaTime);
            HandleMovement();
        }
        else if (Speed < allowPlayerRotation)
        {
            animator.SetFloat("Speed", Speed, StopAnimTime, Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }

    private void CheckGround()
    {
        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(transform.position, groundCheckDistance, LayerMask.GetMask("Grounded"));
        animator.SetBool("isGrounded", isGrounded);
    }

}
```